# Validate url with query string containing email address using PHP

Tags: php, regex, url, email-validation, url-validation

Hi I have problem with correct url validation with query string containing email address like:

`https://example.com/?email=john+test1@example.com`

this email is ofc correct one `john+test1@example.com` is an alias of `john@example.com`

I have regex like this:

```
$page = trim(preg_replace('/[\\0\\s+]/', '', $page));
```

but it don't work as I expected because it replaces `+` to empty string what is wrong. It should keep this `+` as alias of email address and should cut out special characters while maintaining the correctness of the address.

Example of wrong url with `+`:

`https://examp+le.com/?email=example@exam+ple.com`

Other urls without email in query string should be validating correctly using this regex

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I advise you to use https://regexr.com/ for testing, it could be very useful

Comment: Why do you need to pass email as GET param? Can't you build your logic in a different way?

Comment: You should [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) any value you send as a query parameter in the URL. Otherwise, the browser will interpret special characters (like `+` being a substitution for a space). The browser can't know that you want a literal plus sign. Also, why do you validate the query string as part of the URL? Could you explain what that "validation" actually is for?

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~[\0\s]+|\++(?=.*\?)|(\?.*)~', '$1', $s)`

Comment: it's an old piece of code where function x sets header() with this url to redirect user to customized url with his email address in query string and user can set his email with `+` and it makes a problem

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it still don't work

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove the lookahead, it should be [`preg_replace('~[\0\s]+|\++|(\?.*)~', '$1', $s)`](https://regex101.com/r/oFsXPy/1/)

Comment: still doesn't work for me coz it should return whole address like `https://example.com/?email=john+test1@example.com` or this `https://example.com/?email=john+test1@example.com&email2=john+test2@example.com` even when I use incorrect like this:
`https://exam+ple.com/email=john+test1+@example.com&email2=john+test2@exam+ple.com`

Comment: I do not think it is possible as you want to remove `+` inside valid English words, right?

Comment: it should remove from this example:

`https://exam+ple.com/email=john+test1+@example.com&email2=john+test2@exam+ple.com` 
only `+` from words `exam+ple.com` `test1+@example` `@exam+ple.com` 
but not from `john+test1@`

Comment: What are the rules here? Why do you think regex will help?

Comment: only one correct rule is to set `+` as alias to proper email address like `example+test@example.com` where `+test` is an alias for `example@example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for:

```
<?php

function replace_plus_sign($string){
    return
    preg_replace(
        '/#/',
        '+',
        preg_replace(
            '/\++/i',
            '',
            preg_replace_callback(
                '/(email([\d]+)?=)([^@]+)/i',
                function($matches){
                    return $matches[1] . preg_replace('/\+(?!$)/i', '#', $matches[3]);
                },
                $string
            )
        )
    );
}

$page = 'https://exam+ple.com/email=john+test1+@example.com&email2=john+test2@exam+ple.com';
echo replace_plus_sign($page);
```

Gives the following output:

```
https://example.com/email=john+test1@example.com&email2=john+test2@example.com
```

At first, I replaced the valid `+` sign on email addresses with a `#`, then removing all the remainings `+`, after that, I replaced the `#` with `+`.

This solution won't work if there's a `#`s on the URL if so you will need to use another character instead of `#` for the temporary replacement.

Comment: if you remove `@` from here:

return $matches[1] . preg_replace('/\+(?!$)/i', '#', $matches[3]) . '@';

it will be perfect